# React Bootstrap Dropdown Menu closes when clicking on an input

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsx

I have been bumping my head against this question for a while now. I realize it has been asked before on SO, but none of the questions I saw were exactly the same (either they were not relevant to React or had an answer that wasn't working).

My problem is that I have a dropdown menu made with React-Bootstrap with a nested text input. When I click on the input, the menu automatically closes.

I have tried, according to some answers, to stopPropagation of the event, but when I do this, I cannot write anything on the input field. Furthermore, neither stopImmediatePropagation nor preventDefault work at all.

Here is my dropdown as it renders inside the component:

```
    <ButtonGroup>
      <DropdownButton className="filter-ddown1" id="filter-ddown1" title="Rango de Precio">
        <MenuItem className="itemxx" href="#"><input className="minmax" onClick={this.dontClose} type="text" placeholder="Min" value={this.props.state.minPrice}></input><label> - </label><input className="minmax" type="text" placeholder="Max" value={this.props.state.maxPrice}></input></MenuItem>
      </DropdownButton>
    </ButtonGroup>
```

And here is the dontClose function (which avoids writing anything on the input field):

```
  dontClose:function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
```

I thank you in advance if you can help.

Comment: make a fiddle..

Comment: Im sorry, but I'm pretty new with web. Could you please expound?

Comment: well, in order for anyone to test this they will have to download the js plugins and make a write up all the code. since this is a free forum people are unlikely to to spend all that time and effort. in cases like these it is helpful to make a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so people can see the problem in action. alternatively there is a section in the question editor which allows you to do the same thing. it's the 7th button to the right, with the `<>` symbol on a page.

Comment: I'm searching for this same answer right now